# Send default WooCommerce email when switching from custom order status

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, order, email, post-status

I have implemented custom order status `on-review` and now I need to send WooCommerce default on-hold email when switching order statuses from `on-review` to `on-hold`.

In order to do this, I have to add new `woocommerce_order_status_on-review_to_on-hold_notification` action that will run `trigger` method of `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` class.

It looks like there are no hooks nor filters to add this action to default `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` constructor and I have to override this class with custom one. To do so, I need to define my custom `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` class after `WC_Email` class is defined, and before `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` class is defined.

The problem is that both these classes are included during `init` method execution of `WC_Emails` and there are no hooks between file inclusions.

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was overcomplicating things. This is the solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'custom_woocommerce_email_classes', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_classes( $email_classes ) {
    $email_classes[ 'WC_Email_Customer_On_Review_Request' ] = include_once 'includes/classes/class-wc-email-customer-on-review-request.php';

    // Register custom trigger to send on-hold email when status is switched from on-review to on-hold.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-review_to_on-hold_notification', [
        $email_classes[ 'WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order' ], 'trigger'
    ], 10, 2 );

    return $email_classes;
}
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you than you should accept your own answer.